# C++ binary file

Tags: c++, binary

I've created a binary file using `ios::binary`
but my file is showing me text output.
Why? and How can I create a binary file which shows in binary representation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("lab11.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
int marks,roll_no,n,i;
char name[100];
cout<<"\nEnter the no of students:\n";
cin>>n;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cout<<"\nEnter name of student:\n";
    cin>>name;
    outputFile << name << "\n";
    cout<<"\nEnter Roll no.:\n";
    cin>>roll_no;
    outputFile << roll_no<<"\n";
    cout<<"\nEnter Marks:\n";
    cin>>marks;
    outputFile << marks<<"\n";
}
outputFile.close();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For files opened in binary mode usage of `write` and `read` methods are recommended. Do not use binary stream output like `outputFile << roll_no<<"\n";`

See [C++ references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/)